# Understanding the "Just one more" paradox on a logarithmic scale

Tags: logarithms, expected-value, economics, paradoxes, utility

I got somewhat puzzled after watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FuuYSM7yOo) on [Kelly Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) in economics and the associated "just one more" paradox. This question should be self-contained, so watching the video itself is not necessary.

**Setup**: We have $V_0 = 100\$$ to start with, and throw an unbiased coin. In case of heads, we gain 80%, resulting in $V_1 = 180\$$, in case of tails we lose 50%, resulting in $V_1 = 50\$$. While the video considers playing multiple consecutive games, this question relates to playing only a single game.

We can find the expected value of this game, namely
$$\langle V_1 \rangle = 0.5\cdot 180 + 0.5\cdot 50 = 115$$
And thus the expected gain is positive
$$\langle V_1 - V_0 \rangle = 115 - 100 = 15$$

**Problem**: Now, I propose to convert this game to a logarithmic scale. The original equation for this game is
$$V_1 = V_0 X$$
where $X$ is the multiplier of the coin toss, namely $1.8$ or $0.5$. We can take the base 10 logarithm of both sides
$$\log_{10} V_1 = \log_{10} V_0 + \log_{10} X$$
We can rewrite the above equation, defining new variables for the corresponding terms
$$W_1 = W_0 + Y$$
Finally, we can calculate the expected gain in this log-view of our game
$$\langle W_1 - W_0 \rangle = \langle Y \rangle = 0.5 \cdot 0.255 + 0.5 \cdot (-0.301) = -0.023$$

**Question**: So, in the original view this is a winning game, in the logarithmic view it is losing game. Why is that? Do I have a mistake in my calculation, or maybe the assumption that the two games are equivalent is wrong?

Comment: This looks ok? Note the expected value of $V_1/V_0$ is still $1.15$. It’s just not true that the expected value of $\log V_1/V_0$ is the $\log$ of the expected value of $V_1/V_0$

Comment: I don't get the motivation for the question. You're taking logarithms and it produces changes. Let's assume that instead of logarithms you just subtract, say, $1000$. Would you still expect a positive expected value? In any case, you forgot to add $\log_{10}(100)$ on the computation of the "second" term (where you got $-0.301$).

Comment: @FShrike yes, two formulas are different thus the different results. That makes perfect sense. The question though is to understand what does this imply. Is the logarithmic view faulty in some way?

Comment: Faulty? I'm not sure what you mean. But it's admittedly counterintuitive that the expected value of the logarithm is negative. This is an example of Jensen's inequality, actually; we have $\Bbb E[\log X]\le\log\Bbb E[X]$

Comment: @GitGud The motivation is that it is commonplace in many sciences to work with data on a logarithmic scale solely because it is more convenient. One would naively assume that, since logarithm is a monotonic function, increases or decreases in the exponent should translate to increases or decreases in absolute value. My aim is to protect myself from future misuses of statistics. I am sorry, I'm not sure where is the missing term, could you clarify? To the best of my understaing, log10(100) is on the other side of the equation

Comment: @FShrike By faulty I mean that performing a mapping to a log-space seems to lead me to the wrong conclusion that I stand to lose money by playing this game many times. I am trying to understand why that happens

Comment: @AleksejsFomins $0.5\left(\underbrace{\log_{10}\left(100\right)+\log_{10}\left(1.8\right)}_{\sim2.255}\right)+0.5\left(\underbrace{\log_{10}\left(100\right)+\log_{10}\left(0.5\right)}_{\sim 1.699}\right)=\sim 1.977$

Comment: @GitGud, but that is not what I am calculating. I am calculating the expected value of Y, which is log(X), which is log(1.8) or log(0.5). Where does the extra log(100) come from?

Comment: @PatrickT Sorry, I still don't follow. Where exactly is the minus sign missing? Can you point to the specific line?

Comment: @PatrickT Why should it be -0.5? An expected value, by definition, is a sum of values multiplied by their probabilities.

Comment: @PatrickT Yes, and $W_1 - W_0 = Y$, right? So the expected value of the left side is equal to the expected value of the right side. Since $Y = \log_{10} X$, its expected value is just a sum by the definition of expected value, not a difference. Again, what exactly am I missing?

Comment: @PatrickT Did you see my previous reply? There is no minus in front of -0.5. If there is a minus, then please provide proof for it.

Comment: You made a sign error, let's see if you can find it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**Original Case :**

Proportional Change $ W = + 0.5 \times (0.8) - 0.5 \times (0.5) = 0.40 \times 0.25 = 0.15 $

Actual Change $ 0.15 \times 100  = 15 $ : POSITIVE !

**New Case :**

Proportional Change $ W = + 0.5 \times \log [ (0.80) ] - 0.5 \times \log [ (0.50) ] = 0.5 \times 0.204 = 0.102 $

Actual Change $ 0.102 \times 100  = 10.2 $ : POSITIVE !

We get Positive Change in linear & logarithmic Calculations.

**No Change Case :**

Let us say winning gives $+80$ , while losing give $-80$ :

Proportional Change $ W = + 0.5 \times \log [ (0.80) ] - 0.5 \times \log [ (0.80) ] = 0.5 \times 0 = 0 $

We get $0$ Change in linear & logarithmic Calculations.

**Negative Case :**

Let us say winning gives $+80$ , while losing give $-90$ :

Proportional Change $ W = + 0.5 \times \log [ (0.80) ] - 0.5 \times \log [ (0.90) ] = 0.5 \times [8/9] = -0.051 $ : Negative !

Actual Change $ -0.051 \times 100  = -5.1 $ : Negative !

We get Negative Change in linear & logarithmic Calculations.

**Summary :**

That Change is logarithmic , hence the value will not match the linear non-logarithmic Change , in general.
It will always match the SIGN.

**ADDENDUM :**

Why did I calculate Proportional Change & then Multiplied that by 100 to get Actual Change ?

(A) When Subtracting $\log$ values , the $+ \log 100$ will cancel with the $- \log 100$ ( It will cancel during Division ) & hence it will not matter.

(B) When Adding the $\log$ values , it will generate $+ \log 100 + \log 100$ which is $+ \log 100^2$ ( Involving the Square of the Initial Amount ) which is totally unrelated to the Calculations.

Hence , I ignored that Constant , introducing it when necessary.